# multiple ajax calls on button click if page is not refreshed jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

If I click the Submit button once then the AJAX call is executed only once. This is perfect.

The problem is if I don't refresh the page and click the Submit button for the second time, then the AJAX call is executed twice. If I click the button for a third time without refreshing the page, the AJAX call is executed thrice.

What is wrong with my code? I want the AJAX call to be executed only once when I click the Submit button.

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <input type="hidden" name="buttonId" id="buttonId">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span id="commspan" class="input-group-addon">Comment</span>
          <input type="text" name="queuqOther" id="queuqOther" class="form-control">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" id="btnPause" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

```js
$('#btnPause').on('click', function() {
  var form = $("#myForm");
  form.validate();
  if (form.valid()) {
    $.ajax({
      async: true,
      crossDomain: true,
      url: "http://localhost/postdata",
      xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: `$('#btnPause').off().on('click'...` You keep attaching a new handler every time.

Comment: Nothing about your the code you've shown is attaching multiple event handlers, so I'm unsure why people are suggesting `off()`. Is there any other logic called when the AJAX returns as this code will not cause the behaviour you describe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest tweak would be to remove the listener once you check that the form is valid:

```
const $btnPause = $('#btnPause');
const handler = function() {
  var form = $( "#myForm" );
  form.validate();
  if(form.valid()){
    // remove handler:
    $btnPause.off('click', handler);
    $.ajax({
      async : true,
      crossDomain: true,
      url: "http://localhost/postdata",
      xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
      },                            
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  }
};

$btnPause.on('click', handler);
```

Comment: Seems fine to me https://jsfiddle.net/w159bj24/ What exactly is the error you're running into?

Comment: @CertainPerformance the OP isn't binding multiple events here, so I don't see why `off()` would make any difference.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I thought the problem was that multiple clicks of "submit" result in multiple ajax calls, for which I thought the obvious solution was to just remove the handler the first time an ajax call is getting sent out. Am I missing something?

Comment: I removed $btnPause.off('click', handler); and changed $btnPause.on('click', handler); to $btnPause.unbind().bind('click', handler); and it worked

Comment: Thank you very much. Please update your answer with what I suggested above so that it will help others :)

Comment: @pravinnavle Wait, `$btnPause.unbind()`? Was *another* listener attached to that button previously which is sending out ajax requests or something? I don't see anything like that in your question?

Comment: That was the point I was trying to make before, but the OP appears to have made it work. The problem code is something outside of what was shown in the question.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I think there must be some other event listener attached to the button

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes I think problem code was outside of the code shown in the question

Comment: guys please check my [new question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53894075/angularjs-filter-based-on-matching-values-in-nested-array)

Answer (score 2):

Try removing `click` event handler with `off()` as Following

```
$('#btnPause').off('click').on('click',function() {
  var form = $( "#myForm" );
  form.validate();
  if(form.valid()){
    $.ajax({
              async : true,
              crossDomain: true,
              url: "http://localhost/postdata",

              xhrFields: {
                 withCredentials: true
                },                            
              success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                  }
          });
    }
});
```

You can also use `one()` to execute the event handler at most once

```
$('#btnPause').one('click',function() {/* your code here */});
```

Answer (score 1):

Always unbind the event handlers once you complete binding. For eg. use .off() for .on() attached events.

```
$('#btnPause').off('click').on('click', function() {
//your Code Here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const $btnPause = $('#btnPause');
const handler = function() {
  var form = $( "#myForm" );
  form.validate();
  if(form.valid()){
    // remove handler:
    $btnPause.off('click', handler);
    $.ajax({
      async : true,
      crossDomain: true,
      url: "http://localhost/postdata",
      xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
      },                            
      success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  }
};

$btnPause.on('click', handler);
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome, It is recommended to explain your code when posting the answer please :)